# connecting MATLAB to Apache Derby database via JDBC

Tags: java, matlab, jdbc, derby

I've been asked to connect an Apache Derby database to our existing MATLAB data-mining tools.  I am running MATLAB R2014a (no Database toolbox)

After some research and trial and error, here's what I did:

went to http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloadderbyclientjar.htm and downloaded derbyclient.jar and saved it, and unzipped it to a shared folder.

edited the text file C:\Users\tyler.davis\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014a\javaclasspath.txt and added full path to derbyclient.jar, saved it, restarted MATLAB.

At MATLAB command line

```
javaclasspath
```

shows "S:\SHARED...\derbyclientjar\derbyclient.jar\derbyclient.jar" at the end of the static path list.  So far so good.

Next, try

```
driverClassName = 'org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver';
java.lang.Class.forName(driverClassName);
```

reports error:

```
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/derby/jdbc/ClientDriver

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

Tried an alternative:

```
classLoader = com.mathworks.jmi.ClassLoaderManager.getClassLoaderManager;
driverClass = classLoader.loadClass(driverClassName);
```

That seemed to work, created objects "driverClass, type 1x1 java.lang.Class" and "classLoader, value 1x1 com.mathworks.jmi.ClassLoaderManager"

Then I tried

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(driverClass.newInstance);
```

which reports error

```
Undefined variable "DriverManager" or class "DriverManager.registerDriver".
```

and if I try to create a sample database using

```
cxnStr = 'jdbc:derby:sampleDB:create=true';
cxn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(cxnStr);
```

I get

```
Java exception occurred:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:sampleDB:create=true

at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I really don't know what I'm doing here; just copying other's code from around the web.  Any suggestions on what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just getting started with Derby, can I recommend that you take an hour or two and run through the Derby tutorial:  http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html

Also, can I recommend that you get in the habit of downloading Derby from the Apache website rather than other Internet sites? The copies of Derby on other sites are probably fine, but it seems most reliable and safest to get Derby from the Apache website: http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html

Most of what you did in your description seems OK to me; I suspect the place where you went astray is when you unzipped derbyclient.jar itself.

Although a '*.jar' file is in fact a valid ZIP archive, you are not expected to unzip those packaged jar files. Instead, you should leave the jar as 'derbyclient.jar' and then set your CLASSPATH to include 'derbyclient.jar' as one of the entries in the CLASSPATH list.

Lastly, note that the JDBC Connection URL

```
jdbc:derby:sampleDB:create=true
```

is a correct JDBC Connection URL for the **embedded** configuration of Derby, not for the **client-server** configuration of Derby.

So even if you get a good copy of derbyclient.jar into your CLASSPATH correctly, you won't be able to use

```
jdbc:derby:sampleDB:create=true
```

Instead, you'll either have to use a client-server style JDBC Connection URL, such as:

```
jdbc:derby://my.server.name:1527/sampleDB
```

(and learn how to operate a Derby Network Server), or you'll need to switch to using the Embedded Driver (org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver).

For more information about this notion of configurations, see: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/cgsquck70629.html

And for more information on the JDBC Connection URL and the two JDBC driver classes, see: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/cgsquck19524.html

Once you've had a chance to work through the Derby Getting Started guide, I recommend asking some follow-on questions based on what you learn during that experience.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason I went to a different site is that I had initially tried to download directly from apache.org (both the db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin.zip and db-derby-10.11.1.1-lib.zip) and during the unzipping process, I got this error message: "an unexpected error is keeping you from coying the file....0x80004005...derbyTesting.jar"

Comment: I should have been more clear; the file I downloaded from java2s was a zip file containing a single jar file.  I unzipped the zip, not the jar.  Now that I understand the difference between the two configurations, I want the embedded database, not the client/server.  The database will reside locally on the PC and be accessed by only one user at a time.  I will try working on the EmbeddedDriver

Comment: Indeed, I sometimes have problems with the Apache "download mirrors". It sounds like your download was not complete, because the zip was damaged. Did you verify the md5 signature of the download after it completed? I suggest you discard the damaged bin.zip and lib.zip archives and freshly re-download them from Apache, using a different download mirror if necessary.

Comment: No, I didn't verify the checksum, but the fact that both files could not be unzipped tells me all I need to know.  I now realize that the person who made the Derby database for us saved a "dist" folder which contains derby.jar, so I'll just point to that in my CLASSPATH and skip any downloads.  That way I'm sure that my driver is in sync with the derby version used to build the database.

Comment: OK, I was able to connect using the EmbeddedDriver!  Now I have to learn some SQL syntax to build my queries.  It would be helpful to have a Java IDE so I can browse through my database to understand its structure.  Is there anything out there that doesn't require me to install software (and engage the dreaded IT dept)?

Comment: Good to hear! For interactive JDBC work, I like SQL Squirrel: http://sourceforge.net/projects/squirrel-sql/

Comment: OK, I was able to import my sample database into a MATLAB dataset.  I used nested row/column loops to fetch a single record at a time.  This seems terribly inefficient, but all the sample code I found tells me that it is necessary since JDBC uses a pointer that must be advanced row-by-row.  When I scale up this method to a large derby database, the import becomes painfully slow.  I've read mixed advice on whether JDBC is faster or slower than ODBC.  Should I try ODBC fetch, and can I use it to access an Apache Derby database without the MATLAB Database toolbox?